# why is bufferedwriter not writing in the file?

Tags: java, io, bufferedwriter

Here is the code snippet.

```
read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filenames[i]);
                br = new BufferedReader(read);
                while((lines = br.readLine())!=null){
                    st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("files/file.txt"));
                        bw.write(st.nextToken());
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
```

Edit:
I am reading files from a directory. So, I need to open the reader in every loop. I have made some modification, but then also it is not writing to that file. 
Here is the code:

```
for(i=0;i==0;i++){
            if(filenames[i].matches(".*ham.*")){
                System.out.println("ham:"+filenames[i]);
                read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filenames[i]);
                br = new BufferedReader(read);
                while((lines = br.readLine())!=null){
                    st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                       bw.write(st.nextToken());
                    }
                }
                bw.close();
                br.close();

            }else{
                System.out.println("spam:"+filenames[i]);
            }
                        }
```

edit:
I modified the code, but no success,

```
while((lines = br.readLine())!=null){
                    st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("files/file.txt"));
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                       bw.write(st.nextToken());
                    }
                    bw.close();
                }

                br.close();
```

And i am getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
    at Test.main(Test.java:30)`

edit:
Thanks guys.. I figured it out. Actually I created an directory in eclipse and I did not refresh it to see the content. Its silly... anyways.thanks a lot

Comment: Is there an error message? Is a file created? Are you calling close()?

Comment: Why do you instantiate a new BufferedWriter for every write you do? Besides, you should always close all open streams (after the work is done, ofc :-)).

Comment: After your last edit you're still creating the BufferedWritter inside the loop. This will truncate your file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- You are creating the FileWritter inside the loop so you will always truncate the file in each cycle.
- You forgot to close / flush the writter
- But with some luck (terminating the program may cause the writter to flush) the file would contain the last word of your input file which I can only guess would be a new line and you probably missed when you opened up the file to check the content.

Your inner loop should be something like this:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"))) {
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        bw.write(st.nextToken());
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not complete, for instance I didn't declared the Tokenizer which looks like is causing the exception. It's just a sample to guide you :)

Comment: bw.close() is very important. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: `bw.close()` will not be called in case of some `IOException` in the code snippet you've provided. Please, consider using `try-with-resources` construct in your answer.

Answer (score 20):

A couple of things:

1. You're creating a new FileWriter each time through the loop, which will truncate the file each time.
2. BufferedWriter is buffered, and you're never flushing the buffer.  You need to either call bw.flush(), or even better, close the writer when done.

Comment: Better, flush the decorator in the happy case. Close the underlying resource in `finally`. (ObFileWriterComment: `FileWriter` picks up the character encoding that happens to be the "default" at the time. Much better to explicitly choose an encoding, which means shunning `FileWriter` (use `OutputStreamWriter`).)

Comment: closing provides an implicit flush, so in most simple code closing in a finally is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use following Constructor to create `FileWriter`,

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("files/file.txt",true));
```

Second parameter, `true` is for appending the new data. `FileWriter` will not truncate your previous write.

and your reader will be able to read proper data.