# How to generate log files that is received by my Java Server from android client?

Tags: java, logging, text-files

I have a working system here which communicates my android client to my Java Server. Basically it just send a message by my android client and my server receives it by `System.out.println(message);` . Now what I want to happen is to save all receives message to a single textfile that will serve as my logs and it will update as soon as my server receives a new message.

```
while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Message from " + message + " at " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                    str.append(message+"\n");


                }
```

This one is a part of my Java Serve code. BTW I am using TCP port to communicate my server and my client thru the same network. I want to save to a textfile the text that is holded by the str string. How can I do that? Or is that possible? Thanks in advance!

Kindly check out my code:

```
PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/foo.txt")));
                while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Message from " + message + " at " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                    str.append(message+"\n");
                    out.println(message);


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to achieve file output is to run the Server code with an output redirection

```
java -cp<Whatever classpath> ServerClassName >file &
```

If you need to write to a file from java, you can use following pseudo code

```
PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));
while ( read message as you doing now)  {
    // do something 
    out.println(message);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I can't understand this statement
java -cp<Whatever classpath> ServerClassName >file &
What is Whatever classpath? And where should i declare this?

Comment: Do you want to see the whole code of mine? Wait I'll update the post.

Comment: I meant how are you executing the code? Is it from some kind of IDE or you running from command prompt?

Comment: Updated! @Akhilesh Singh

Comment: JAVA ECLIPSE is where i run it.

Comment: So you can forget about the first approach. It is relevant for only command prompt.You will need to use the PrintWriter method.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Does it will save a log.txt for example? because i need logging the messages that the server receives.

Comment: "foo.out" is filename which you can change to suit your needs.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for your help. Keep you updated if i succeed in this stuff.

Comment: Hey there! @Akhilesh Singh Its not working. Is my syntax correct? Check out my post. I've posted the code.

Comment: Refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430143/why-is-bufferedwriter-not-writing-in-the-file. Essentially, you are using BufferedWriter and will need to call close/flush or wait till internal buffer of BufferedWriter is full.